# JSON Key Value Error Confusion

Tags: python, json, facebook

I keep getting a KeyError: 'message' and I am not sure why?

Here is a sample of that data I am parsing:

{

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": "86264418970_10152060349923971",
        "from": {
            "category": "Health/beauty",
            "category_list": [
                {
                    "id": "181045748599578",
                    "name": "Personal Trainer"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Infinite Fitness - Personal Training",
            "id": "86264418970"
        },
        "to": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "category": "Kitchen/cooking",
                    "category_list": [
                        {
                            "id": "132852590115660",
                            "name": "Kitchen Supplies"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "150060378385891",
                            "name": "Appliances"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Vitamix",
                    "id": "89031985873"
                }
            ]
        },
        "message": "Favourite Things Friday! \nThis a new feature for 2014. Every Friday will feature a product, business, person, quote, etc that is our absolute favourite!! If you have ideas or want to share your favourite thing, let us know.\n\nThis week, it's the Vitamix! Honestly it's the one kitchen appliance that I just can't live without. Although shakes are nothing new in our world, the degree to which the Vitamix blends is incomparable to anything I've seen. It has made adding a variety of veggies (broccoli, spinach, kale, beets, carrots) a breeze as it blends to a completely smooth consistency. \n\nBonus points, the kids LOVE the shakes and little do they know all the amazing things they're getting with it. \nExtra bonus points, although I don't do it often, I have made soup and ice cream with it. Super easy.\nExtra extra bonus points, clean up is a snap! Less than a minute, no joke.\n\n(The favourite things feature is my own opinion and although I gush, I am not being paid to do so)",
        "message_tags": {
            "245": [
                {
                    "id": "89031985873",
                    "name": "Vitamix",
                    "type": "page",
                    "offset": 245,
                    "length": 7
                }
            ]
        },
        "privacy": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "type": "status",
        "application": {
            "name": "Pages Manager for iOS",
            "namespace": "fbpagemanager_ios",
            "id": "165907476854626"
        },
        "created_time": "2014-01-10T15:01:41+0000",
        "updated_time": "2014-01-10T15:01:41+0000"
    },
    {
        "id": "7568536355_10102570693591239",
        "from": {
            "category": "Computers/internet website",
            "name": "Lifehacker",
            "id": "7568536355"
```

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import json
import urllib
import sys
import time
import re

class FacebookSearch(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url_format = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?{query}&{type}&{access_token}'
        self.access_token = 'access_token=XXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXX'

    def make_search_url(self, q, type='post', **queryargs):
        queryargs['q'] = q
        query = urllib.urlencode(queryargs)
        url = self.url_format.format(query=query, type=type,
                                     access_token=self.access_token, **queryargs)
        return url

    def search(self, q, type='post', **queryargs):
        url = self.make_search_url(q, **queryargs)
        page = urllib.urlopen(url)
        return page.read()


def write_csv(fname, rows, header=None, append=False, **kwargs):
    filemode = 'ab' if append else 'wb'
    with open(fname, filemode) as outf:
        out_csv = csv.writer(outf, **kwargs)
        if header:
            out_csv.writerow(header)
        out_csv.writerows(rows)

def main():
    ts = FacebookSearch()
    data = ts.search('appliance')
    js = json.loads(data)

    messages = ([msg['created_time'].replace('T', ' ').replace('+0000', ''), msg['message'].replace('\n', ' ').encode('utf8'),  msg['from']['id']] for msg in js.get('data', []))

    write_csv('fb_washerdryer.csv', messages, append=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the full trace back of the error:

> [ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-164 ~]$ ./facebook_washer_dryer4.sh Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "./facebook_washer_dryer4.sh", line
>   47, in 
>       main()   File "./facebook_washer_dryer4.sh", line 44, in main
>       write_csv('fb_washerdryer.csv', messages, append=True)   File "./facebook_washer_dryer4.sh", line 35, in write_csv
>       out_csv.writerows(rows)   File "./facebook_washer_dryer4.sh", line 42, in 
>       messages = ([msg['created_time'].replace('T', ' ').replace('+0000', ''), msg['message'].replace('\n', '
>   ').encode('utf8'),  msg['from']['id']] for msg in js.get('data', []))
>   KeyError: 'message' [ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-164 ~]$

I have reviewed the json I am parsing up one side and back the other and I dont understand why I would get a "Key Value error".

I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days now and would really like to discover a solution.  Any help or advice would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Try replacing `msg['message']` with `msg.get('message', 'Key "message" is not present.')` and `print `messages` afterwards. It's possible that not all messages in data include a `message` key.

Comment: That totally worked!  Thank you so much Joel.  I would only get the error on 1/2 of the runs of my code.  I couldn't figure out why it would error sometimes and not others.  I never even thought that the message key may not be on all messages.  Really appreciate the insight

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `msg['message']` with `msg.get('message', 'Key "message" is not present.')` and print `messages` afterwards.

It's possible that not all messages in data include a message key. Using `get()` will cause your code to not break in the middle of the list comprehension, allowing you to inspect the results afterwards.